# Compile VB.NET online?

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-construction, frameworks

Is there a website where I can compile VB.NET code online?

Today I've discovered the CodeRun site which it supports online building of C# projects: www.coderun.com/ide/

I'm interested into show some snippets to people, but those people does not have an IDE to run a code or else maybe those people could not know what is an IDE/.NET/VS/Programming so giving the URL of a site to let them build the code by himself is better and "fast-way" for me than compile them by myself to later upload them to a server to later download in their computers to test each snippet as a compiled aexecutable...

Is there a website like CodeRun, but with VB.NET support?

Comment: [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/), pick `VB.NET` from the language dropdown on the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run simple basic code here: http://compileonline.com/. I use it for simple C, and Java for the same reasons, but I'm not sure how complicated it goes.

Here is the link straight to VB.NET: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_vb.net_online.php

Comment: @ElektroHacker no problem.  I only found the site a couple of weeks ago too.  It's fun to mess around with new languages and not have to worry about compilers, too.